# ¿Cómo obtener LAST INSERT en Web Service en PDO?

Tags: php, webservice, pdo

Les muestro mi script PHP para conexión a la base de datos, es con una clase y un try catch:

```
class conexionDBUsuarios{
    private $servidor;
    private $base_datos;
    private $usuario;
    private $contrasenia;
    private $charset;
    public function __construct(){
        $this -> servidor = 'localhost';
        $this -> base_datos = 'usuariosbj';
        $this -> usuario = 'root';
        $this -> contrasenia = '';
        $this -> charset = 'utf8mb4';
    }
    function conexionDBUsuarios(){
        try{
            $cadena_conexion = "mysql:host=" . $this -> servidor . ";dbname=" . $this -> base_datos . ";charset=" . $this -> charset;
            $opciones_atributos = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            $cadena_conexion_db = new PDO($cadena_conexion, $this -> usuario, $this -> contrasenia, $opciones_atributos);
            return $cadena_conexion_db;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo ("Error: Fallo al conectar a MYSQL, no se pudo establecer conexión con la base datos de usuarios en el servidor: (Información de Error: ' . $e -> getMessage() . ')");
        }
    }
}
```

Bien, estoy intentando "consumir" un web service en PHP/PDO en el cual se genera una sentencia INSERT y quiero obtener el LAST INSERT pero me arroja un 0 al momento de hacerle un JSON_ENCODE (Aclaro que apenas estoy comenzando con esto de los WS) le muestro el script del Web Service:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $sentencia = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, contrasenia, id_cargo) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :contrasenia, :id_cargo)";
    $sql = $conexion_usuarios -> conexionDBUsuarios() -> prepare($sentencia);
    $sql -> bindValue(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $sql -> bindValue(':usuario', $_POST['usuario']);
    $sql -> bindValue(':contrasenia', $_POST['contrasenia']);
    $sql -> bindValue(':id_cargo', $_POST['id_cargo']);
    $sql -> execute();
    $id_post = $conexion_usuarios -> conexionDBUsuarios() -> lastInsertId();
    echo $id_post;
    if($id_post){
        header("HTTP/1.1 202 OK");
        echo json_encode($id_post);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

¿Qué debo hacer para que funcione correctamente?
Estoy usando MySQL para gestionar la información en la base de datos ¡Ayuda!

Comment: Conviene leer lo que dice [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php): *Este método puede no devolver resultados significativos o consistentes para diferentes drivers PDO, debido a que la base de datos subyacente puede no soportar el concepto de campos auto-incrementales o secuencias.* Significa que si la tabla no tiene una columna auto-increment o no soporta secuencias, no funcionará. Háblanos sobre cómo está estructurada tu tabla, para verlo puedes ejecutar en `SHOW CREATE TABLE usuarios;` y analizar el resultado.

Comment: Cada vez que llamas `conexionDBUsuarios()` creas una conexión nueva, entonces te regresa el último id de **otra** conexión. Extiende PDO e instancía una vez, o asegúrate que en el flujo de tu código haces `new PDO()` sólo una vez. Es un buen momento para que revises el [*Patrón Singleton*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#PHP5).